# Copying entire line of source code in Google Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, screen-scraping, web-inspector

I am trying to copy a whole line of source code, which is very long and so spreads across thousands of rows. Is there a shortcut to copying the whole line (either using python or just on chrome)? The link to the website is: https://www.whoscored.com/Matches/1648652/Live/England-League-One-2022-2023-Barnsley-Portsmouth . Specifically I am trying to copy the 'matchCentreData'.

I have tried selecting it all manually, but it often bugs and doesn't work because there are so many rows. The screenshot just shows the first few rows. If someone could help that would be greatly appreciated. [image: part of code that I am trying to copy (it extends much further than what is shown)]

Comment: Would it help if you could get that data via JS?  `requirejs.s.contexts._.config.config.params.args.matchCentreData`

Comment: @JonSG Thanks for your reply. What exactly is JS? Is that something I can use in python to extract the matchCentreData?

Comment: Type that into your browser console to get the result you seek.